# Laravel Chart Label

Tags: php, database, laravel, charts, label

I have fetched a column from the database called 'result' with values of 0s and 1s and create a pie chart based on that data.

Right now i don't know how to label/rename the chart such as 0 as Normal and 1 as Malicious.

This is my code in HomeController:

```
$chart8 = Charts::database(Ujian::all(), 'pie', 'chartjs')
      ->title("Log Result")
      ->responsive(false)
      ->width(0)
      ->elementLabel('Malicious', 'Normal')
      ->groupBy('label');
```

and this is the display:

[image: pie-chart]

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit further your question? Wich package are you using? It seems to be [ConsoleTVs/Charts](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts)

Comment: i use the materials from here https://erik.cat/projects/Charts/docs/5